# Get second last version of all objects from S3 efficiently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there an existing way to download the 2nd last version (if available) of all available objects from S3 that has versioning enabled?

Or a version of objects before a certain date & time.

I am thinking about a hypothetical situation where a ransomware encrypts all files.

I am assuming one would have to script the following

1. Get a list of all objects.
2. Fetch the available version of each object.
3. Match a condition for selecting the version.
4. Download the object.

Is there a better way than the above, considering the following two scenarios and notes from AWS docs.

Scenarios:

1. There are 10000 objects with very few versions of each file (new deployment)
2. There are 10000 objects with 500+ versions of each file (old deployment)

Notes:

> To list all the versions of all the objects in a bucket, you use the versions subresource in a GET Bucket request. Amazon S3 can retrieve a maximum of 1,000 objects, and each object version counts fully as an object. Therefore, if a bucket contains two keys (for example, photo.gif and picture.jpg), and the first key has 990 versions and the second key has 400 versions, a single request would retrieve all 990 versions of photo.gif and only the most recent 10 versions of picture.jpg.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html

Comment: Sounds like you can read all the versions in the bucket.

Comment: Yes, but there is a limit of 1000 per query.
It would have been ideal if one could retrieve the last X number of versions of each current object.

Comment: No such API exists.  You either need to paginate through all of the versions, or enable a S3 Inventory report with versioning enabled, and parse the report that produces.